# How to set the Identify Feature tool in QGIS 2.4?

Tags: qgis

The Identify Results window does not appear when using the identify feature tool  in QGIS 2.4.
I guess there's a check box somewhere I need to check/uncheck, but the settings of the tool changed compared to the previous version (see attached printscreen).
[image: QGIS 2.2 on the left and 2.4 on the right]

Comment: Does the feature form appear instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on the toolbar and select **Identify Results**

The options for the different select modes has been moved to the dock widget.

Answer (score 5):

Use the shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + I` to access the identify results, this will avoid problems about versions.